# Spring Integration Infinite Loop on any Exception in Custom Error Channel

Tags: spring-integration

We have a custom error channel for our application which mainly notifies integration failures via Email. When there is an exception thrown in the SendEmail Http call (WebFlux.outboundGateway) of the custom error channel, the integration flow goes on an infinite loop.

Please help stop this behavior

```
    @Bean("appErrorChannel")
    public MessageChannel appErrorChannel() {
    
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    
    @Bean("appErrorFlow")
    public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
    
        // @formatter:off
        return IntegrationFlows.from(appErrorChannel())
                                .<MessagingException> log(ERROR, message -> "Exception: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(message.getPayload()))
                                .transform(transformer, "errorMessage")
                                .transform(transformer, "emailRequest")
                                .log(INFO, message -> "Email Request: " + message)
                                .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                                .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, errorFlowErrorChannel()))
                                .handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway(sendEmailURL, webClient)
                                                .httpMethod(POST)
                                                .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                                                .mappedRequestHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE))
                                .log(INFO, message -> "Email Response: " + message)
                                .get();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean("errorFlowErrorChannel")
    public MessageChannel errorFlowErrorChannel() {
    
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
        
    @Bean("errorChannelErrorFlow")
    public IntegrationFlow errorChannelErrorFlow() {
    
        // @formatter:off
        return IntegrationFlows.from(errorFlowErrorChannel())
                                .<MessagingException> log(FATAL, message -> "Exception in Error Flow: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(message.getPayload()))
                                .get();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
2022-04-09 11:45:11,198[0;39m [boundedElastic-1          ] [31mERROR[0;39m [36mo.s.i.w.o.WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler[0;39m - [35me2abc8b6eba0119c[0;39m Failed to send async reply
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application-1.appErrorChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST ****** URL ******, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=******* SUPPRESSED ********}, headers={b3=e2abc8b6eba0119c-c4254a192695705d-1, nativeHeaders={}, errorChannel=bean 'appErrorChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [**************}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:457)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendErrorMessage(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:496)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler$ReplyFutureCallback.onFailure(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:555)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallbackRegistry.notifyFailure(ListenableFutureCallbackRegistry.java:86)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallbackRegistry.failure(ListenableFutureCallbackRegistry.java:158)
.....
.....
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really not recommended to have a single global error channel for the whole application.

Consider to have its own error channel for this specific error handling flow.
Set it via `enrichHeaders(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, "errorFlowErrorChannel")` and there is not going to be an infinite loop because an error from the `WebFlux.outboundGateway()` is not going to be forwarded to the `appErrorChannel` any more.

Comment: Yes, was thinking the same to have an `errorFlowErrorChannel`. Why do u think the single global error channel is not a good idea, as it seems independent of all functional flows and only job of it is to log and notify. Thanks

Comment: With the behavior seen with infinite loop, messages consumed from a channel are transactional by default, so it is really thrown back rather than forwarded? Please correct if this understanding is wrong

Comment: `.enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, errorFlowErrorChannel())` is not respected even after adding just before the WebFlux call. Still the message has original headers as such preserved in the transformers  to `appErrorChannel`

Comment: The header enricher could be configured with an `override` option. Otherwise existing header is not overridden. Another way is to remove the `errorChannel` header before web flux. This way the error indeed will go to the global `errorChannel`. If you don’t override it of course… my point was do not do some hard error handling logic in that global error channel